# How do I style new DOM entries in an array using ractive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ractivejs

I have a Ractive instance that modifies an array. When new values appear  in the array, I'd like to have the corresponding element highlighted. I currently do this by having some styling on newly created elements. **Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemaccana/uz73baqd/1/)**.

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

    {{ #things:index }}
      <p>{{ things[index] }}</p>  
    {{ /things }}

  `,
  data: function(){
    return {
      things: [
        'banana',
        'carrot'
      ]
    }
  },
  oncomplete: function(){
    var component = this;

    setTimeout(function(){
      component.set('things', ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'])
    }, 5 * 1000)
  }
});
```

The only issue is that since ractive re-uses elements, the styling appears on the wrong element.

You'll see when  `'banana', 'carrot']` is changed to `['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']`, the `'carrot'` element is highlighted, instead of the `'apple'` element that corresponds with the new value.

**What's the best way to style new entries in an array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `recentlyAddedThings` cache to add a cache of added items. Here's a **[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemaccana/uz73baqd/3/)**:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: `

    {{ #things:index }}

      <p class="{{ #if recentlyAddedThings.includes(things[index]) }}new{{ /if }}">
        {{ things[index] }}
      </p>  
    {{ /things }}

  `,
  data: function(){
    return {
      things: [
        'banana',
        'carrot'
      ],
      recentlyAddedThings: [

      ]
    }
  },
  oncomplete: function(){
    var component = this;

    var addThing = function(newThing){
      var things = component.get('things')
      var newThing = newThing
      things.push(newThing)
      component.set('things', things.sort())
      component.push('recentlyAddedThings', newThing)
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
      addThing('apple') 
    }, 2 * 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
      addThing('avocado') 
    }, 3 * 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
      addThing('cheese')  
    }, 4 * 1000)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `splice` method

```
 component.splice('things', 0, 0, 'apple');   // Add at zero index   
 component.splice('things', 1, 0, 'apple');   // Add at first index
```

rather than setting whole array again. This is equivalent to `Array.splice` method.

Whole code will look like this.

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

    {{ #things:index }}
        <p>{{ things[index] }}</p>  
    {{ /things }}

  `,
  data: function(){
    return {
        things: [
        'banana',
        'carrot'
      ]
    }
  },
  oncomplete: function(){
    var component = this;

    setTimeout(function(){    
        component.splice('things', 0, 0, 'apple');
    }, 5 * 1000)
  }
});
```

Read more about it here.
https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractivesplice

Comment: Hrm `splice()` works but I need the elements / items in order. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: @mikemaccana I think you should refer  their official documentation. There is an equivalent `Array.prototype` method in `Reactive` for each function. https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractivesplice

Comment: I'm aware of this, but that doesn't answer the question of how to highlight new elements corresponding to new array items.

Comment: What do you mean by *items in order.*

Comment: As in each `thing` in `things` being in some kind of order, eg, alphabetical or any other comparison function you'd pass to `array.sort()`. I see ractive has https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractivesort but it's unclear if there's any inbuilt way to highlight elements corresponding to recently added array items.